# "Have or celebrate" holidays

Tags: word-choice

Can I use "such as" and "like" interchangeably in my sentence and do you use "have" or "celebrate" when you talk about celebrations?

- "My country **has** many public holidays **such as/like** New Year, Christmas, Men's Day, and Woman's Day, etc".
- "We **have** or **celebrate** Woman's Day."
- "1st May is a holiday or a day off."
- "9th May is a Victory Day."
- "People **have** holidays in May."
- "I mean public holidays."

Comment: The country _has_ those public holidays in its calendar, but people celebrate them (or 'get those  days off [work]'). _Such as_ and _like_ are more or less equivalent here.

Comment: _Women's Day_ and not "Woman's Day". Also, "9th May is **the** Victory Day" not "a". It is something unique, hence definite article must be used.

Answer (score 1):

> My country has many public holidays such as/like New Year, Christmas, Men's Day, and Woman's Day, etc".

That is correct and either *such as* or *like* would work. If they are all genuinely days of celebration then you could replace *has* with *celebrate* but if some of them are just public holidays with no real meaning then *has* is the only choice. In my country we have so-called Bank Holidays and these have gradually been decoupled from the event which they originally celebrated and an extra one inserted to fill a gap so we have the days off but we do not have anything to celebrate. So I would say we have the late August Bank Holiday but it seems a stretch to say we celebrate it.

> We have or celebrate Woman's Day.

Here *celebrate* would be correct.

> 1st May is a holiday or a day off.

That is fine

> 9th May is a Victory Day.

Unless your country celebrates many Victory Days the *a* is incorrect.

> People have holidays in May.

That is correct too.

Comment: I don't think August Bank Holiday was ever anything but an extra day off in late summer.

Answer (score 0):

"Such as" introduces *examples*. "Like" draws a *comparison*. Saying you have holidays "such as Christmas" means Christmas is an example of a holiday, but saying the holidays are "like" Christmas means that the others are similar to Christmas. I think you should use "such as".

---

The word "holiday" is used quite differently between British English and American English.

- In US English, a 'holiday' always means a public holiday such as Christmas, Easter etc.
- In British English, a 'holiday' is time off work or school, either spent at home or away somewhere - what Americans call a 'vacation'. Our public holidays are always referred to as "public holidays" or, more commonly "bank holidays". We tend to call specific holidays like Christmas by their name.

Also the word "celebrate" usually implies some kind of festivities. Not all public holidays involve celebrations - some are just a day off work.

So British people tend not to say that they "celebrate holidays". They might talk about celebrating Christmas. If it was a more serious or somber event such as Remembrance Day we might say "observe". For any other non-specific day off work or school we would probably say we "have" a holiday, or "it is" a holiday.